# Can't start MySQL - no space left on device

Tags: centos, mysql

I am not able to start MySQL, on a CentOS 6 system. When I checked in the `mysqllog` the error I get is

```
121117 11:16:19 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Error writing file '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid' (Errcode: 28) 
121117 11:16:19 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: No space left on device 
121117 11:16:19 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
```

I ran a `df -h` command and if I am not wrong, `/var/` disc usage is 4% only.

```
/dev/sda6              16G   15G     0 100% /
tmpfs                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             194M   51M  134M  28% /boot
/dev/sda3            1008M  284M  674M  30% /tmp
/dev/sda5            1008M   34M  924M   4% /var/tmp
/dev/sdb1              79G  184M   75G   1% /mnt/vol1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/var/tmp` partition is at 4%

Your `/var` folder will be under the `/` root partition which is at 100%

Comment: so andrew what can i do to resolve this. Till yesterday it was working fine. I am new to linux based systems

Comment: The usual hog is `/var/log` - purge some of the old logs (and setup `logrotate` if you aren't already using it).  Are you SysAdmin?  If not, talk to the SysAdmin